# Where can I locate/download/purchase the "Tara Ashtakam"

Tags: sanskrit, tara

Where can I locate/download/purchase a sanksrit copy of the tara ashtakam (तर अष्तकं)?

I've seen several english translations and even [this](http://pedia.desibantu.com/tara-ashtakam/) sanskrit translation, which seems to contain errors and who's authenticity I'm uncertain of, but no concrete, accurate sanskrit copy.